# How to use the LinearGradient in a ShapePath?

Tags: qt, qml, shapes, linear-gradients

I'd like to draw a gradient inside a custom shape. I have used the property **fillColor** previously and try to use the property **fillGradient** now. The shape is fine I would say - at least it looks like expected :) What isn't fine in any way is this gradient thing. It just doesn't look anything like expected.

Here is what I want to do. This should run as it is in Qt Design Studio.

```
import QtQuick 2.15 
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15 
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15 

Rectangle {
    id: btn
    color: "white"

    readonly property alias fieldHeight: p.fieldHeight

    Shape {
        ShapePath {
            id: p
            property int r: 172
            property int fieldWidth: 123
            property int fieldHeight: 79
            property int deltaX: 30
            startX: 0
            startY: 0
            strokeColor: "black"
            strokeStyle: ShapePath.SolidLine
            fillGradient: LinearGradient {
                GradientStop {
                    position: 0
                    color: "#6c6c6c"
                }
                GradientStop {
                    position: 1
                    color: "#000000"
                }
            }
            PathArc {
                id: upperBorder
                x: p.fieldWidth
                y: 0
                radiusX: p.r
                radiusY: p.r
            }
            PathLine {
                x: p.fieldWidth - p.deltaX
                y: p.fieldHeight
            }
            PathArc {
                x: p.deltaX
                y: p.fieldHeight
                radiusX: p.r
                radiusY: p.r
                direction: PathArc.Counterclockwise
            }
            PathLine {
                x: 0
                y: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not specifying the start and end point of the line that the gradient should follow. Qt annoyingly has 2 different objects called `LinearGradient` and they have different property names. One is from QtGraphicalEffects, and the other is from QtQuick.Shapes. You're using the shapes version, so your gradient should look something like this:

```
fillGradient: LinearGradient {
    x1: 0
    y1: 0
    x2: p.fieldWidth
    y2: p.fieldHeight

    GradientStop {
        position: 0
        color: "#6c6c6c"
    }
    GradientStop {
        position: 1
        color: "#000000"
    }
}
```

Comment: A big "thank you" for that great and rapid answer :) That's what I call a Christmas present ;) But I must say I have had those X and Y properties defined in a previous version and it did not work. But I remember I have had some calculations in it so maybe I mixed up some wrong numbers ;)